# Form doesn't working properly

Tags: php, html

If all inputs are filled, everything works just fine. But if I check just checkbox, the form let me register, no matter I didn't fill all the inputs.
Also if add var_dump to the bottom of the page ( when just checkbox is checked) it says "boolean false " Please help...

```
<?php

    $page_title = 'Registracija'; // Definiše title i h1

    $folder = 'registration-db';

    if (!file_exists($folder)) {

        mkdir($folder, 0777, true);`enter code here`

    }

    $fajl = $folder . '/registrovani_korisnici.txt';

    // Citanje podataka
    if (file_exists($fajl)) {
        $podaci = file_get_contents($fajl);

        $registracija = explode("\n", rtrim($podaci)); //Vracanje података iz baze
    }



    $errors = false;




    //Obrada forme i provera podataka

    if (!empty($_POST)) { //ako nije prazna promenljiva


        //Provera da li su podaci unešeni


        if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste upisali ime i prezime!<br>';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['user_email'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste uneli E-mail!<br>';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {// Izbacio !empty($_POST['user_email']) &&
            $errors[] = 'Nije validna email adresa!<br>';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['user_password'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste uneli lozinku!<br>';
        }
        if (strlen($_POST[]) <= 5) {  //radi
            $errors[] = 'Lozinka mora da ima više od 5 karaktera!<br>';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['user_password2'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste potvrdili lozinku!<br>';
        }

        if ($_POST['user_password'] !== $_POST['user_password2']) {
            $errors[]  = 'Lozinka mora da bude ista u oba pokušaja!';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['day']) || empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['year'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste uneli ispravan datum!<br>';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['check'])) { //radi
            $errors[] = 'Niste prihvatili uslove korišćenja!<br>';
        }

        /*if (date('Y') - $_POST['year'] < 15) {
            $errors[] = 'Nemate dovoljno godina, da biste se registrovali!<br>';
        }*/ //Problem kada se ne definiše vrednost  $_POST['year']!!!!!

        else {
            // Data forwarding
            extract($_POST);

            // Name

            // Skidanje tagova - Zbog bezbednosti!!!
            $user_name = strip_tags($user_name);
            //Pretvaranje u mala slova
            $user_name = strtolower($user_name);
            //Pretvaranje prvih slova u velika (Ime Prezime)
            $user_name = ucwords($user_name);


            // Čišćenje Email-a
            $user_email = strip_tags($user_email);


            //Čišćenje Lozinke
            $user_password = strip_tags($user_password);

            //Čišćenje Lozinke2
            $user_password2 = strip_tags($user_password2);

            /*html_entity_decode();
            htmlentities();*/


            $podaci .= $user_name . '#!$!#' . $user_email . '#!$!#' . $user_password . '#!$!#' . $user_password2 . '#!$!#' . $day . '.' . $month . '.' . $year . '#!$!#' . PHP_EOL;

            //Zapisivanje u fajl
            file_put_contents($fajl, $podaci);


            header('Location: registracija.php?sent=1');
        }


    }

    ?>



    <?php include 'inc/header.php'; //include header?>

    <!-- Prikazivanje greške-->

    <?php if ($errors !== false) : ?>

        <p>GREŠKA: </p>

        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>

            <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if (isset($_GET['sent']) && $_GET['sent'] == 1): ?>
        <h2>Uspešno ste registrovani! Hvala.</h2>

    <?php else : ?>


        <!-- Form -->
        <form action="" method="post">

            <p>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Ime i prezime">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="E-mail">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Lozinka">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="password" name="user_password2" placeholder="Ponovite lozinku">
            </p>

            <h2>Datum rodjenja</h2>

            <select name="day">

                <option selected disabled>Dan</option>
                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) : ?>
                    <option> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
                <?php endfor; ?>

            </select>

            <select name="month">

                <option selected disabled>Mesec</option>
                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) : ?>
                    <option> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
                <?php endfor; ?>

            </select>

            <select name="year">

                <option selected disabled>Godina</option>
                <?php
                $start = date("Y");
                $end = date("Y") - 100;
                ?>
                <?php for ($i = $start; $i >= $end; $i--) : ?>
                    <option> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check"> Prihvatam uslove korišćenja

            <p>
                <button>Registrujte se</button>
            </p>
        </form>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Form END -->
    <?php include 'inc/footer.php'; //include footer?>
```

Comment: Did you set a value for checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to turn you if statements into a if - else if - else chain. In your situation, if last if statement returns false, your former validations become void.

```
if (empty($_POST['day'])) {
    //Validation
}
else if (empty($_POST['year'])) {
    //Validation
}
else if (empty($_POST['check'])) {
    //Validation
}
// Other validations
else {

}
```

Also, you should add a value to your checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" />
```

This way, if it's checked, it will post a value.

In your current situation, even if checkbox is checked, you don't send any value and your last if statement evaluates to false.

**EDIT:**

To display all missing fields at once, you just change your else statement into another if-else statements like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Niste upisali ime i prezime!<br>';
}
if (empty($_POST['check'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Niste prihvatili uslove korišćenja!<br>';
}
//Other validations

if($errors) {
    //Show errors
}
else{
    // Data forwarding
    // Same as your former else statement
}
```

Comment: @Dena Are you sure the problem is in the last if statement? Because if it evaluates to false, it's impossible to run the else statement.

Comment: @Dena also, may you try to change you last if statement like this? `if (isset($_POST['check']))`

Comment: @Dena I've edited my question and added an explanation to achieve to display all missing fields at once. I've simplified it to improve readability, so  feel free to ask if you get stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's a small logical error. Your `else` block is only associated with your last `if` block. As a result, `else` will be entered if the last `if` block is not executed.

If `$_POST['check'] is not empty that is if the condition inside the last`if block` returns false then the else will be entered and registration gets completed.

What could you do to get around this?

Use a flag. Declare a variable as `$c=1;`. We will change the value of this variable to `0` if any `if block` is entered.

```
 $c=1;
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste upisali ime i prezime!<br>';
    $c=0; 
    }
    if (empty($_POST['user_email'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste uneli E-mail!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }
    if (filter_var($_POST['user_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {// Izbacio !empty($_POST['user_email']) &&
    $errors[] = 'Nije validna email adresa!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['user_password'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste uneli lozinku!<br>';

    $c=0;
    }
    if (strlen($_POST[]) <= 5) {  //radi
    $errors[] = 'Lozinka mora da ima više od 5 karaktera!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['user_password2'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste potvrdili lozinku!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }

    $if ($_POST['user_password'] !== $_POST['user_password2']) {
    $errors[]  = 'Lozinka mora da bude ista u oba pokušaja!';
    $c=0;
    }
    $if (empty($_POST['day']) || empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['year'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste uneli ispravan datum!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }
    $if (empty($_POST['check'])) { //radi
    $errors[] = 'Niste prihvatili uslove korišćenja!<br>';
    $c=0;
    }
     elseif ($c==1)
    {
    //CODE
    }
```

`else if` block will only be entered if `$c==1` is true.

You could also use `if-elseif-else` ladder.

OR:
You can use the `required` attribute in each input tag to force the users to fill that particular field before submitting.

```
    eg:

        <input type="email"  name="user_email" Placeholder="Email" required>
```

Add the `required` attribute in each input tag to stop the form from getting submitted if a field is not entered.

For example, in the above case, the form wouldn't get submitted if email-id is not entered.

Comment: Well. I'll just edit my answer. But required attribute would be helpful too.

Comment: @Dena If you use the required attribute, the form won't get submitted if the compulsory field is not filled. This could be an answer for your question. Validation comes after submitting the form. Using required will show an error in place before submitting. Isn't that a good idea?

Comment: Alright. But would you mind if I keep the post as it is (in case it becomes useful to someone else)??

Comment: @Dena Edited the answer with expected solution.